# comparing torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss with label as int and prob tensor produces an error

Tags: pytorch

I have this criterion:

```
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
```

And during training phase i have:

```
label = tensor([0.])
outputs = tensor([[0.0035, 0.0468]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward>)
```

When i try to compare them:

```
 criterion(outputs, label)
```

I get this error:

```
    ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Long but got scalar type Float for argument #2 'target' in call to _thnn_nll_loss_forward
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) expects its `label` input to be of type `torch.Long` and not `torch.Float`.
Note that this behavior is opposite to [`nn.BCELoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCELoss.html#torch.nn.BCELoss) where `target` is expected to be of the same type as the input.

If you simply remove the `.` from your label:

```py
label = torch.tensor([0])  # no . after 0 - now it is an integer
```

pytorch will automatically create `label` as `torch.Long` type, and you are okay:

```py
In [*]: criterion(outputs, torch.tensor([0]))
Out[*]: tensor(0.7150)
```

---

*Commenting on the other answers by [planet_pluto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64982368/1714410) and [Craig.Li](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64982335/1714410):*

1. A more general way of casting an existing tensor is to use [`.to(...)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.to):

```py
label = torch.tensor([0]).to(dtype=torch.long)
```

However, creating-and-casting is not  very efficient way of doing stuff:
Think of it, you make pytroch create a `torch.float` tensor and then cast it to `torch.long`.

2. Alternatively, you can explicitly define the desired `dtype` upon creation of the tensor:

```py
label = torch.tensor([0.], dtype=torch.long)
```

This way pytorch creates `label` with the desired `dtype` and no 2nd phase of casting is required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your label to a `torch.LongTensor` tensor.

`label = tensor([0.]).type(torch.LongTensor)`

Answer (score 0):

`nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` expects targets of type `torch.LongTensor`. Just do this:

`label = tensor([0.]).long()`